# Dragging panel does not reduce opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am rather new to HTML and javascript and have started a project in mvc5, currently I am trying to implement drag and drop panels and have been following a tutorial.  However the problem is when I try to drag the panel(to my belief) the javascript code does not run,  this is probably due to it being incorrect but I cannot see what is wrong. Here is the tutorial I am following http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Here is the javascript code

```
function handleDragStart(e) {
    e.target.style.opacity = '0.4';  // e.target is the source node.
}

var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');

[].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
    col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
});
```

and here are the panels I am trying to drag:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MovieLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Welcome to your dashboard!</h2>

<div class="row" id="columns">
    <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have referenced my javascript file within the head tags in the layout shared view like so.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/Scripts/dashboard.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("MVCMovie", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard")">
                            Dashboard
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" />
                            </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Devices")">
                            Devices
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Alerts")">
                            Alerts
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Services")">
                            Services
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Settings")">
                            Settings
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Whitespider.eu</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Now your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/jj7dy6ca/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referenced my scripts at the end of the layout just below the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` line I think it needed to load the jquery files first before I run any javascript.  I could be wrong but this sorted it, if someone has a more accurate explanation please feel free.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the wrong element!

```
document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');
```

But you have `.panel`

Working Example:

```js
function handleDragStart(e) {
this.style.opacity = '0.4';  // this / e.target is the source node.
}

var columns = document.querySelectorAll('.column');

[].forEach.call(columns, function (column) {
    column.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
});
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
<div class="row" id="columns">
<div class="col-md-4 column">
    <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 column">
    <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 column">
    <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi SharpEdge I just tried your code but does not seem to work.  I did not provide the whole html for my panels, could you have another look.  I have edited my post just after you had replied.

Comment: It works in the code snippet you gave, however for some reason it does not work on my project.

Comment: I put it into firebug and examined the columns variable however it doesnt seem to be picking up any of my elements, nodelist length is 0

Comment: I will edit my post to include the relevant parts, my layout, the view and the js reference